# System.InvalidCastException: can't figure out why exactly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I altered my stored procedure to indicate whether the authenticated user is an instructor or a student or an admin ..the Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   myLogin.submitID_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) +191
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

and here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
    /*
    (
    @parameter1 int = 5,
    @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
    )
    */
    (

    @Email nvarchar(50),
    @pass nvarchar(50),
    @outres int = null OUTPUT,
    @outres1 int = null OUTPUT,
    @outres2 int = null OUTPUT,
    @outres3 int = null OUTPUT,
    @kind int = null OUTPUT
    )
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
     DECLARE @UserId INT



    set @outres1 =  (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Admins 
WHERE admin_Email=@Email AND admin_Pass=@pass)
if (@outres1=1)
 begin
 set @kind=1
 set @outres=@outres1
 SELECT @UserId = adminID
      FROM [dbo].Admins WHERE admin_Email=@Email AND admin_Pass=@pass

      set @outres1= @UserId
    RETURN @outres 
    end

set @outres2= (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Instructors 
WHERE inst_Email=@Email AND inst_Pass=@pass)
if (@outres2=1)
 begin
 set @kind=2
 set @outres=@outres2
 SELECT @UserId = instructorID
      FROM [dbo].Instructors 
WHERE inst_Email=@Email AND inst_Pass=@pass
  set @outres2= @UserId
 RETURN @outres 
    end
set @outres3= (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Students 
WHERE stu_Email=@Email AND stu_Pass=@pass)
if (@outres3=1)
begin
set @kind=3
set @outres= @outres3
SELECT @UserId = studentID
      FROM [dbo].Students 
WHERE stu_Email=@Email AND stu_Pass=@pass
 set @outres3= @UserId
RETURN @outres 
end 
else
begin
set @outres=@outres3
set @outres1=0
set @outres2=0
set @outres3=0
RETURN @outres
end
```

and when a student logs in it's fine and Response.Redirect goes to the specified page but not the instructor. I tried redirecting the instructor to the student page and it also didn't work and now no one can login. Here's the code-behind :

```cs
public int Validate_Login(String _Email, String _Password)
{
    string lbl;
    string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    SqlCommand cmdselect = new SqlCommand();
    cmdselect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdselect.CommandText = "[dbo].[StoredProcedure1]";
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = _Email;
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = _Password;
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@outres", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@outres1", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@outres2", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@outres3", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@kind", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
    cmdselect.Parameters["@outres"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmdselect.Parameters["@outres1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmdselect.Parameters["@outres2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmdselect.Parameters["@outres3"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmdselect.Parameters["@kind"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmdselect.Connection = con;
    int Results = 0;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        // SqlDataReader rd = cmdselect.ExecuteReader();
        cmdselect.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
        cmdselect.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //cmdselect.ExecuteScalar();
        /* if (rd.HasRows)
          {
              rd.Read();
             // lblinfo.Text = "You are Authorized.";
              FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(ETB.Text, true);
              Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
          }
          else
          {
              lblmsg.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
          }*/
        Results = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@outres"].Value;
        int res1 = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@outres1"].Value;
        int res2 = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@outres2"].Value;
        int res3 = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@outres3"].Value;
        int knd = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@kind"].Value;
        if (Results == 0)
        {
            Session["userID"] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (res1 != 0)
            {
                Session["userID"] = res1.ToString();
            }
            else if (res2 != 0)
            {
                Session["userID"] = res2.ToString();
                Session["userKind"] = knd.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Session["userID"] = res3.ToString();
                Session["userKind"] = knd.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        lbl = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmdselect.Dispose();
        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return Results;
}

protected void submitID_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Results = 0;
    DataBind();
    Results = Validate_Login(ETB.Text.Trim(), pwdTB.Text.Trim());
    if (Results == 1)
    {
        Session["user"] = TextBox1.Text;
        int ukind = (int)Session["userKind"];
        if (ukind == 3)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx#profile");
        }

        if (ukind == 2)
        {
            Response.Redirect("welcomeNew.aspx");
        // Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx#profile");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        // Response.Redirect("welcomeInstructor.aspx");
        }
    /*  if (Page.PreviousPage == Session["prevPage"])
        {
            Response.Redirect("courses.aspx");
        }*/
    }
    else
    {
        lblmsg.Text = Results + " Email and Password don't Match !";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
    }
// }
/*   lblmsg.Text = "Please make sure that the username and the password is Correct";
       lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;*/
}
```

please help...

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or more info about the exception you're getting? Presumably, those (int) cast's you're doing are the culprit and probably one or all are null. Instead of an implicit cast, grab them as an object first, see what type they are in the profiler (probably DBNull) and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: At a minimum tell us what line is throwing the exception. There's no point in someone reading all the other code if it's not the part that's failing.

Comment: you're right guys I edited it

Comment: Which line is line 191 ?

Comment: Most likely its this `int ukind = (int)Session["userKind"];`

Comment: well I tried this `int ukind = Int32.Parse(Session["userKind"].ToString());` but it also throws : `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: it is this line `int ukind = (int)Session["userKind"]; ` that's causing this but how handle it ?and still know if it's an instructor or a student ?